# Import an open street map in android app in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, openstreetmap

I'm new to Android and to Open Street Maps.

I have exported an open street map named "map.osm".

I'm using eclipse for andoid and I have included the following jar files:

- osmdroid-android-3.0.10.jar
- slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar

Now it's time to import the map.osm file.
Shall I use tiles in order to display the osm in android?

[I downloaded **Maperitive** and I created tiles in .png format]

Can anyone elaborate on that?
What type of file shall I import in eclipse?

- map.osm [open street map file] or
- or tiles in png format?

It's not clear to me the type of osm file I have to import in eclipse.

I would like the user to search specific items on the map e.g.

- restaurants
- hotels
- attractions

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I never used osmdroid you will very likely have to import the `.osm` file, either additionally (if you want to use your tiles for drawing maps) or exclusively (if you want to render vector maps). Tiles are just *raster* images without any metadata. If you need POIs, addresses, streets, cities, opening hours and so on then your application will need the `.osm` file.

Comment: Thanks for replying,is it easy to import the .osm file in android? How can my android method parse the .osm file? Shall I use a DOM parser?Cause I need 1) to display the .osm file in an android app and 2) use the metadata on the open street map but I do not know how to do it...

Comment: Please read my first few words again. osmdroid should do the parsing and everything else for you. If you have more questions then please contact the osmdroid community or start a new question